ADF Pipeline to load data from Excel file located in Teams channel to SQL Server
I have an Excel file populated in Teams channel.  It's a report that gets manually updated every day. I would like to create a pipeline that will load this file to SQL Server database.
Is it doable? I tried a web activity, but not sure if it's a correct way to start.

Teams is just the client and thus I doubt the file is actually saved in somewhere else .. like OneDrive or SharePoint. Confirm that .. and once you know the actual location then yes it's very much doable

If I go to "copy link", I see a sharepoint location.


If I go to "copy link", I see a SharePoint location.

To copy an Excel file from SharePoint to an Azure SQL database, you should first store the file in Blob storage. You can use a Logic App to copy the Excel file from SharePoint to Blob storage. After successfully copying the file, you can use ADF to copy it to the Azure SQL database. If you have only one sheet in excel then select it manually otherwise, follow the procedure below:

Add three variables named c1 with a default value of 0, tempc, and iserror as shown below:


Add an Until activity to the pipeline and set a variable activity with variable tempc using the @string(add(int(variables('c1')),1)) dynamic expression.

Add a Copy activity to the set variable. Select an Excel dataset with index and a dynamic value @int(variables('c1')), and select the Excel file as the source, and an SQL dataset with tableName and a dynamic value excel@{variables('c1')} parameter as sink.

On the success of the copy data, add a Set Variable activity with c1 variable and dynamic value @variables('tempc'). On failure of copy data activity, add a Set Variable activity with iserror and dynamic value @bool(1). Add @variables('iserror') to the Until activity.


Here is the pipeline JSON of the dynamic Excel sheets copy:
{
    "name": "excel",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Until1",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@variables('iserror')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "tempc",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "tempc",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(add(int(variables('c1')),1))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "tempc",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "ExcelSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "Excel1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "c1",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "c1",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('tempc')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "iserror",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Failed"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "iserror",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@bool(1)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "c1": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "0"
            },
            "iserror": {
                "type": "Boolean"
            },
            "tempc": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2024-02-23T08:00:17Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}

Debug the pipeline it will run as shown below:

Excel sheets will copy successfully as tables in the SQL database. Run the below script to show the tables which are copied:
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE =  'BASE TABLE'  and TABLE_SCHEMA =  'dbo'

The script will show the tables as shown below:



TABLE_SCHEMA
TABLE_NAME




dbo
excel0


dbo
excel11


dbo
input


dbo
input1




Thank you!  My main issue is to copy an Excel file from SharePoint to Blob storage.  Is there a way to do it using a linked service or a web activity and without using any additional applications?

No, directly you cannot, you should use copy activity to copy from one to another location.
